# How to deploy Javafx desktop application with Hsqldb

Tags: javafx, deployment, hsqldb

I've completed a Java project with Hsqldb, the application works fine on my local machine, this is intended to be used as a standalone desktop application on the Windows platform. Please could you suggest any references/documentation on how to go about the deployment processes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hm so you need the users of the app to have hsql installed in their computer?

Comment: Using Hsqldb as an embedded db hence do not want users to separately install it.

Comment: Did you use maven or gradle for creating this application? What IDE are you using for this?

Comment: I've used NetBeans IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For deploying an embedded HSQLDB database, the only thing that can be different on the target is the location of the database files.

You define the directory where files are stored and it should be a writable directory. In this case, define the path and use it as an absolute path (which includes the drive name if any) to connect to HSQLDB.

You can also define the database connection URL to contain the user home directory path. This allows storing the database is a subdirectory of the user's home directory. See http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#dpc_variables_url